# Wordpress + Divi + Buddypress - comment reply form not showing

Tags: wordpress, comments, buddypress

I've been searching for solution for some time, but cant figure out what's the problem.

I have installed Wordpress + Divi theme + BuddyPress plugin. But now, when I click on comments button, which should display a form to reply (and it does on other themes), nowthing happens. Well, the window scrolls up like 50-100 px, but the form display is not changing to "block" as it should.

Anyone had similar problem or know where the problem might lie?

Thanks for any help,
Trawa ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the solution is to remove this code from the js/custom.js file, I just commented mine out:

```
$( 'a[href*=#]:not([href=#])' ).click( function() {
if ( $(this).closest( '.woocommerce-tabs' ).length && $(this).closest( '.tabs' ).length ) {
return false;
}

if ( location.pathname.replace( /^\//,'' ) == this.pathname.replace( /^\//,'' ) && location.hostname == this.hostname ) {
var target = $( this.hash );
target = target.length ? target : $( '[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']' );
if ( target.length ) {
et_pb_smooth_scroll( target, false, 800 );

if ( ! $( '#main-header' ).hasClass( 'et-fixed-header' ) && $( 'body' ).hasClass( 'et_fixed_nav' ) && $( window ).width() > 980 ) {
setTimeout(function(){
et_pb_smooth_scroll( target, false, 200);
}, 500 );
}

return false;
}
}
});
```

It worked for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck with that. Same exact problem over here. Makes me regret I paid for Divi before I knew it was jacked up.

Elegant themes ain't talkin'....just says Buddypress is an unsupported 3rd party plugin from what I hear. And the Buddypress threads related to this just close with no solution.

The only clue I've come up with so far is that on the Personal Activity page, if you toggle the dropdown from Everything to Updates etc, sometimes it will kick something in or out that allows the comment button to suddenly work, dropping down the textarea form.

At this point I'm trying to figure out what shakes loose in that scenario. Maybe we can figure this out for those original "developers" who can't seem to drum up a care for this widely complained about issue.